# Error 500 Mercado Pago Curl en PHP

Tags: php, mercadopago, curl, pago-in-app

Tengo el siguiente código que uso dentro de mi servidor, que por algún motivo que desconozco, me manda el siguiente error:

> "{"message":"internal_error","error":null,"status":500,"cause":[]}"

El código que uso para generar el pago es el siguiente:

```
 $url = 'https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments?access_token=TOKEN';

    $fields2 ="{
            'transaction_amount': 100,
            'token': '1fb3f5ef0230718c7eaeeec939eb1bff',
            'description': 'Title of what you are paying for',
            'installments': 1,
            'payment_method_id': 'visa',
            'payer': {
                    'email': 'test_user_19653727@testuser.com'
            }
    }";

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set options 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("accept: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields2); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($result);
```

No comprendo porque del error si a lo que veo todo esta correcto, podría ser algo del `json` que se esté enviado?

Espero y contar con su ayuda.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que se debe a que el Json en el string se esta enviando con un formato incorrecto se debe usar `"` en lugar de  `'`para evitar estos problemas sugiero usar en lugar de un string un array de la siguiente manera.

```php
<?php

    $token = "ACCESS_TOKEN";

    $url = "https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments?access_token=" . $token; 

    $payment_data = array(
        "transaction_amount" => 100,
        "token" => $card_token,
        "description" => "Title of what you are paying for",
        "installments" => 1,
        "payment_method_id" => "visa",
        "payer" => array(
            "email" => "demo@mail.com"
        )
    );


    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set options 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("accept: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payment_data));  

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        var_dump($result);

?>
```